# Magento 2: Could Not Parse Theme Static File

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to override magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js however once I do so, I get:

```
Could not parse theme static file 'app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Magento_Configurable_Product/web/js/configurable.js'
```

I'm well and truly confused on what this could be, I've triple checked the names and directories and I'm 99% sure they're correct and follow the correct flow. The path to the override file is:

```
app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Magento_Configurable_Product/web/js/configurable.js
```

I've searched around and haven't found anything similar so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the correct folder name is Magento_ConfigurableProduct which I discovered after checking the requirejs-config.js!